# pyramid traversal return data from database (mongodb)

Tags: python, mongodb, pyramid

resources.py:

```
class Root(object):
    __parent__ = __name__ = None

    def __init__(self, request):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.request = request
        self.collection = request.db.post

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if u'post' in key:
            return Post()
```

in Root resources, I can return any data on database using request.db.post, then I made another resources :

```
class Post(dict):

    def __init__(self, request):
        super(Post, self).__init__()
        self.__name__ = u'post'
        self.__parent__ = Root
        self.collection = request.db.post
```

I got an error: `__init__()` takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

then I remove the

```
self.collection = request.db.post
```

on Post, and no error return, but I can't return any data from database from Post, so how do I return any data from database from another resources other than Root?

Answer (score 2):

You create a `Post()` instance without any arguments, but your constructor expects you to pass in a `request` parameter. Either pass in the request or remove the parameter requirement:

```
return Post(self.request)
```

or:

```
class Post(dict):
   def __init__(self):
       # ...
```

I don't know how you access your database normally; if the only way to access your database through `request.db` then pass on `self.request` to your `Post()` instances and access `self.request.db` in your `Post` class.

Comment: i've tried but it still doesn't work, looks like the problem is from `__init__(self, request)` from Post, when i remove `request` and `self.collection` no error return, but i still cannot return any data from database using another resources other than root

Comment: @FarisNasution: You're correct, and my analysis is wrong; your constructor expects a request object but you never pass it in. In fact, the `super()` call for dict works just fine. Corrected the answer.